# Laravel wrapping int parameters with backtick

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

In my Laravel query builder, I have this part:

```
 ->leftJoin('tbluserprivileges', function ($join) use ($id) {
            $join->on('tblprivileges.id', '=', 'tbluserprivileges.PrivilegeID');
            $join->on('tbluserprivileges.UserID', '=', (int)$id);
        })
```

I wanted to have two conditions on a `LEFT JOIN` with the other parameters to be dynamic, which is the user ID. However the SQL output is

```
select `tblprivileges`.`id`, `tblprivileges`.`Description`, `tbluserprivileges`.`UserID` from `tblprivileges` left join `tbluserprivileges` on `tblprivileges`.`id` = `tbluserprivileges`.`PrivilegeID` and `tbluserprivileges`.`UserID` = `1`
```

As you can see, the bit where:

```
left join `tbluserprivileges` on `tblprivileges`.`id` = `tbluserprivileges`.`PrivilegeID` and `tbluserprivileges`.`UserID` = `1`
```

The `1` is being wrapped in backticks ( ` ), therefore it is being read as a column when it isn't. I tried to run the code outside of Laravel and removed the wrapping backticks and everything works fine. I am quite unsure on how to remove the backticks, I tried casting it as an integer but it still doesn't work.

Comment: sounds like you want a 'where' not 'on' ... `where` will allow you to compare a column to value ... `on` is for comparing columns to columns

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer myself a few minutes after posting. The parameter should be casted as in Integer

`$join->on('tbluserprivileges.UserID', '=', DB::raw('CAST(' . $id . ' AS SIGNED)'));`

Comment: What you suggested worked for me, here is the sample code I was using, the line commented out was the old line of code, and the line below is what I changed it to and is now working for me.
```lang-php : $query->leftJoin( 'scheduled_recipients', function( $query ) use ( $scheduled_notifications_id ) {
 $query->on( [
  // [ 'scheduled_notifications_id', '=', $scheduled_notifications_id ], // FIXED: Using CAST to get around Laravel's Query builder adding backticks
  [ 'scheduled_notifications_id', '=', DB::raw( 'CAST( ' . $scheduled_notifications_id . ' AS SIGNED )' ) ]
 ] );
} ); ```